# Firefox new debugger - Where did the file tab go?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

Feel really stupid for asking but where did the file tabs in the debugger go? I can only open one file at a time. If I try to open another one, the file content is simply replaced with the new file. If I revert back to the old debugger, then I have a file tab for each file I open.

Using Firefox 53.0.3 (64-bit) on Ubunto 16.04LTS

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually using the old debugger UI. It's the new frontend that allows to open several files at the same time and looks like this:

[image: Firefox DevTools new debugger frontend]

To toggle the new debugger UI, go to [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config) and set the preference `devtools.debugger.new-debugger-frontend` to `true`.

You may also check whether `browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2` is set to `true`, which controls whether Firefox runs in [multi-process mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox).

Comment: Thanks @sebastian-zartner ! The new debugger ui was effectively set to false. However, it looks like I lost the capability to browse the sources via source-map ... bummer :-(

Comment: Note that the new debugger UI isn't enabled by default for the release channel yet (as of Firefox 53.0.3), i.e. it is not released yet. It is only enabled by default on Firefox Nightly and Firefox Developer Edition so far, as far as I can see. [Bug 1294139](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1294139) aims to enable it by default on all channels.